# Trouble understanding indexed sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, interval-arithmetic

Lets say I am given " find the set" $$\bigcup_{k∈N}B_k$$
$$
B_k = \left[ \frac{3}{k}, \frac{5k+2}{k} \right) 
\cup \{10+k\} 
$$

I understand that $k$ is an argument and $N$ is a set however I have trouble understanding this problem

I think the answer is
$$
\left\{ \left[\frac{3}{1}, \frac{5+2}{1} \right) 
\cup \{10+1\} \right\} 
\cup \cdots 
\cup \left\{ \left[\frac{3}{k}, \frac{5k+2}{k} \right) 
\cup \{10+k\} \right\}
$$

Comment: You have presented some notation and an equation, but, you have not actually stated a mathematical problem.

Comment: For example $B_{10}$ is the set of all numbers from $0.3$ to $5.2$, including $0.3$ but not $5.2$, and also the number $20$.  You then want the union of all such sets $B_k$ where $k$ is in $N$ (which might be $\mathbb N$, the natural numbers, i.e. the positive or non-negative integers)

Comment: so a good answer would be [3/1 U 3/2 U 3/3 .....3/k]?

Comment: “a good answer would be…” you still haven’t stated a question, though.

Comment: Find the set...

Comment: Indeed $\left[\frac{3}{1},{5+2\over 1}\right) \cup \{10+1\}$ has something to do with the answer, but putting the extra set of $\{\cdots\}$ braces around it is a mistake. Do you see why?

Comment: Why? ..........

Comment: I think you're supposed to try to "simplify" the answer, which would include merging any overlapping intervals and using as few braces as you can. Also, if $k\in\mathbb N$ is the range of the index, you're not supposed to stop at any particular value of $k$.

Comment: $\left[\frac{3}{1},{5+2\over 1}\right) \cup \{10+1\}$ is a set and you can take its union with other sets simply by writing $\left[\frac{3}{1},{5+2\over 1}\right) \cup \{10+1\}\cup\cdots.$ But $\{\left[\frac{3}{1},{5+2\over 1}\right) \cup \{10+1\}\}$ is a different set and when you take the union of **that** set with other sets you get different results.

Comment: thats right k∈N so  instead the last part I should put "...."

Comment: You could, but that's kind of the same thing as if you are asked what is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/2^n$ and your answer is $1/2+1/4+1/8+\cdots.$ I think you are expected to simplify further.

Comment: something like {3,7}U{11}....k+4?

Comment: I would love to see your answer David

Comment: On an unrelated note, I don't think this question really fits with discrete mathematics as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify your doubt: the second part (curly braces) is just a union of one element (just a natural number $10+k$ here) with the first part (the set). Let's look at those part by part.

For the first part note that we have a union of $[3/k,5+2/k)$. For a natural number k, 3/k runs from 0 to 3 and 2/k runs from 0 to 2. Hence, the union $\cup_{k\in N} [3/k,5+2/k)$ gives us (0,7).

The second part is easy. Just a set of natural numbers starting from 11 (10+1). The union $\cup_{k\in N} \{10+k\}$ gives us $\mathbb{N}-\{1,2,...,9,10\}$

So, the final answer is $$(0,7)\cup\mathbb{N}-\{7,8,9,10\}$$

Comment: The first union never 'gets' 0 so it should be $(0,7)$ unless I am mistaken. Otherwise this looks correct.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for pointing it out.